# Do Lightsabers actually draw Blaster bolts towards themselves thereby making it easier for Jedi to redirect them?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, lightsaber

Do lightsabers draw Blaster bolts toward their blade, thereby easing the Jedi's task of redirecting them against the enemy? Or do the Jedi redirect the bolts toward the lightsabers? If the answer is neither, then I just might have a problem suspending my disbelief. ;)

Comment: I always assumed that it was neither and it was a Jedi's use of the force that tells them the path of the shot so a Jedi knows where to hold his Light Saber to block. similar to when Luke is being taught by Ben on the Millennium Falcon blindfolded, Luke had to feel out the force to show him where that blaster bit was floating and when it was going to shoot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, blocking blaster fire with a lightsaber is a matter of skill, not an inherent ability of the weapon itself or the result of the Jedi manipulating the direction of travel of the bolt.

Analysis of the original trilogy has revealed that [blaster bolts appear to travel at the absurdly low speed of 78 miles per hour](http://www.wired.com/2012/05/star-wars-blaster-speed/), but this is presumably not the case in-universe;  in any case, this wouldn't explain how Jedi are able to deflect bolts which they aren't able to see, as when Luke is training with the remote aboard the Millennium Falcon.

> In order to teach students to draw upon the Force rather than rely on their senses, early level Shii-Cho **blast-deflect training** was conducted with a blindfold, forcing the initiate to rely upon his instincts.
>
> After only a single **training session** with Obi-Wan Kenobi, Skywalker was already **highly competent at blast-deflection**, and he improved his technique over the next three years through pure improvisation.
>   -  [Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_combat)

And:

> "**A lightsaber... only achieves worth in how it is wielded** - in the effort, the struggle of one who holds it."
>   -  Kreia, *Star Wars:  Knights of the Old Republic II:  The Sith Lords*
>
> "[Soresu is] a… defensive technique. But effective. Use it if you do not wish to be hit, or if you are facing many opponents with blasters. With a lightsaber blade and enough **skill in deflection**' it is an excellent offense against blasters, but in other situations, it merely delays the inevitable."
>   -  Kreia, *Star Wars:  Knights of the Old Republic II:  The Sith Lords*
>   [Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_combat)

Wookieepedia suggests that the ability to deflect blaster bolts with a lightsaber is related to the use of the Force:

> The Force played a major part in the Jedi use of a lightsaber, in that their heightened awareness kept them from accidentally injuring themselves while using the weapon in combat, as the blade had no relative weight, making it difficult to judge its position. **Similarly, *the Force* allowed a Jedi to use his/her lightsaber to deflect incoming blaster bolts.** The Force also came into play during the construction of a lightsaber, both in assembling its intricate innards, and the initial charging of the power cell.
>   [Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force)

It appears that lightsabers don't attract blaster bolts, and in most cases, Jedi don't redirect blaster bolts.  It is simply a matter of the Jedi anticipating where the bolt will go, and moving the lightsaber into place in time to deflect it.